# laravel 5.4 how to get intelligent pagination - with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, laravel-5.4

i have following blade temlpate but it is showing all the records like this
[image]

i want pagination like first show 10 and show ... then when somebody click on next then it start showing from 2 to 11 like intelligent pagination, can somebody help me out here

my blade template:

```
<!-- Pagination Start-->
<div id="pagination">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bt-pagination-main">

            <div class="bt-pagination-show">
                <span class="page-show">Show</span>
                <span class="page-show-number">
                  {{Form::select('show_per_page', array('10' => '10' ,'25' => '25' ,'50' => '50','100' => '100','200' => '200') , Session::get('user_config.show_record'),  array( 'class' =>'selectpicker', 'tabindex' =>'7', 'style'=>'width:58px;', 'data-placeholder'=>'10', 'id'=>'show_per_page') )}}
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bt-pagination-number">
                <ul class="bt-pagination">
                    @if($total_pages > 0)
                        @if($page > 1)
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-cls prev" value="">Prev</a></li>
                        @endif

                        @if($total_pages > 1)
                            @for($i = 1; $i < $total_pages; $i++)
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" @if($i === $page) class="page-cls active" @else class="page-cls" @endif>{{$i}}</a></li>
                            @endfor
                            {{--@else--}}
                            {{--<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-cls active">1</a></li>--}}
                        @endif

                        @if($total_pages > 5)
                            <li>...</li>
                        @endif

                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" @if($total_pages === $page) class="page-cls active" @else class="page-cls" @endif>{{$total_pages}}</a></li>
                        @if($page < $total_pages)
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-cls next">Next</a></li>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Pagination End  -->
```

Comment: Laravel has [built in pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination), are you using that?  If so you don't need to write your own front end code, just do something like `$pages->links()`.  As to why you are seeing every page, it is because your code `@for($i = 1; $i < $total_pages; $i++)` iterates over every page and shows i.

Comment: it was working fine with built in but i am using ajax jquery